# ASP.NET C# curl call with OAuth not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

I am trying to do this curl call to the new yahoo weather api with OAuth 1 like so:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getWeather()
{

    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {

        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/");

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_consumer_key = \"(MY CONSUMER KEY)\", oauth_signature_method = \"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp = \"1547473450\", oauth_nonce = \"Ll7ArdU1yN0\", oauth_version = \"1.0\", oauth_signature = \"(MY GENERATED SIGNATURE FROM POSTMAN)\"");

        //httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("OAuth", "oauth_consumer_key = \"(MY CONSUMER KEY)\", oauth_signature_method = \"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp = \"1547472939\", oauth_nonce = \"vu3HE92s6A3\", oauth_version = \"1.0\", oauth_signature = \"(MY GENERATED SIGNATURE FROM POSTMAN)\"");

        HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("forecastrss?location=hamilton&format=json").Result;

        return response;
    }
}
```

But when I run this it returns this error:

> Please provide valid credentials. OAuth
>   oauth_problem="OST_OAUTH_PARAMETER_ABSENT_ERROR",
>   realm="yahooapis.com"

So it appears that my OAuth parameters are missing. My Question is how do I do a curl in ASP.NET C# with OAuth 1 authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out using RestClient

```
var client = new RestClient("http://weather-ydn-yql.media.yahoo.com/forecastrss?location=hamilton&format=xml");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "ac0c256b-e727-4b01-b4fe-edd8b7d7073a");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_consumer_key="(MY CONSUMER KEY)",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1547481203",oauth_nonce="304ixaov43G",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="(MY GENERATED SIGNATURE FROM POSTMAN)"");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```